# What is the preferred method to echo a blank line in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am currently writing some code for a shell script that needs a blank line between two parts of the script, as thus they can be separated when output is displayed to the user.

My question is, I am not sure what the preferred practice is in a shell script for a blank line.

Is it preferred practice to just write `echo` and nothing else or to write `echo " "` as in echo with quotes and blank between the quotes?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`echo` is preferred. `echo " "` outputs an unnecessary space character. `echo ""` would be better, but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 50):

but you can use

```
echo -e "Hi \n"
```

and print a blank line after Hi, with -e interprets the \n character.

Comment: \n to make a blank line is cleaner in the code. Better than having a bunch of echo "". It's a matter of choice, but the code looks cleaner. For places where you need a blank line before and after a line of text use "\n line of text \n"

Answer (score 12):

All of these commands can be used to echo a blank line:

`echo`, `echo ''`, `echo ""`

We cant use `echo "\n"` or `echo '\n'` as they will give output as `\n` in both cases.

Comment: Depending on your shell you can do something like `echo -en "\n"`

Answer (score 10):

In its first implementation, `echo` had no option and outputs optional arguments ending with a new line, so it perfectly suit your needs.

For formatted outputs ending with a new line, `printf` is a better choice, for example : `printf "%s\n\n" "output"`.

Answer (score 4):

## printf

More portable and succinct. This prints a hundred lines.

shell

```sh
printf '\n%.0s' `seq 1 100`
```

bash

```sh
printf '\n%.0s' {1,100}
```

Answer (score 2):

As John suggested use echo. However if you want to print a blank line followed by text and anther blank line - as in running a test then use echo -e suggested by wyanzes.

echo -e "\n Now we are going to load data \n"

puts a blank line before and after.